# How can I share my screen on Google Plus Hangouts?

Tags: google-plus, screencasts

How can I share my screen on Google Plus Hangouts with Linux and Windows computers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<del>This option is not available yet for Hangouts.</del>

**UPDATE January 12, 2012:**

This feature is now officially available. See details [here](https://plus.google.com/115570939558790629700/posts/h9HHTRBK7CJ).

> - Screensharing: share what’s on your computer screen with everyone in the hangout. This is the first of many extras we’re graduating to Hangouts proper.

Comment: Shouldn't there be some way to do it, like pretending your screen is a webcam?

Comment: @RyanTM You'd likely need some program that will interface your webcam and redirect the feed to your desktop.

Comment: @invalidsyntax It needs to take your desktop and pretend it's a webcam. You don't need an actual webcam. See mark4o's answer and http://superuser.com/q/78515/742

Answer (score 10):

There are several applications that allow you to capture your screen (or part of it) and use it as if it was a webcam.  I have used the first two below successfully with hangouts.  I haven't personally tried the others but as far as I know they should work also.

- [WebcamStudio for GNU/Linux](http://www.ws4gl.org/) (Linux)
- [CamTwist Studio](http://camtwiststudio.com/) (Mac)
- [ManyCam](http://www.manycam.com/)
- [Snagit](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit/) ($)
- [ScreenCamera](http://www.pcwinsoft.com/screencamera/) ($)
- [ScreenFlow](http://www.telestream.net/screen-flow/) (Mac) ($)
- [YouCam](http://www.cyberlink.com/products/youcam) ($)

Comment: This question is a list of programs that do the above: http://superuser.com/q/78515/742

Answer (score 7):

As of 2011-09-20, Google released experimental, work-in-progress [Hangouts with extras](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/09/google-92-93-94-95-96-97-98-99-100.html), that adds [Screen Sharing](http://www.google.com/support/plus/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=1257349&topic=1651691&answer=1660627) feature (among [other features](http://www.google.com/support/plus/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=1257349&topic=1651691)).

A friend using Windows could share his desktop with me; but when I tried sharing my Linux desktop, and that "Share Screen" button did nothing. Okay, I know *"The extras are still under construction"*. It will probably (or hopefully) get fixed sometime later.

Meanwhile, it is possible to hack around a virtual webcam using [v4l2loopback](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback) and [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/), as [described by Daniel Kay](https://plus.google.com/110791450453103431565/posts/dN1Sv3pHNe1):

> Linux Screensharing in Google Hangouts
>
> 1. Get https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback
> 2. Build and load module (use modprobe v4l2loobpack debug=(1|2) for testing)
> 3. Compile yuv4mpeg_to_v4l2.c from experimental branch
> 4. mkfifo pipe
> 5. ./yuv4mpeg_to_v4l2 < pipe
> 6. cvlc --vout=yuv --yuv-yuv4mpeg2 --yuv-chroma=I420 --yuv-file=pipe screen:// --screen-width 640 --screen-height 360 --screen-fps 3
>      --screen-caching 200 --screen-top 75
> 7. ???
> 8. PROFIT =)
>
> Play with transcode to get a higher cutout.

Note: I've also tested [WebcamStudio](http://code.google.com/p/webcamstudio/), but its current version requires V4L (instead of V4L2) and thus refused to build against my kernel.

Update on 2012-05-12: Daniel Kay told me he used something similar to [this script](https://gist.github.com/856107).